# how to escape special characters in .gitconfig proxy authentication

Tags: linux, git, bash, proxy

I'm trying to use git behind a proxy and i have set up the proxy details in the .gitconfig files as follows.

```
 [http]
     proxy = http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>
```

The problem is that the username and password field contain the '@' character which needs to 
be escaped.How should it be escaped?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replacing `@` with `%40`. (as illustrated, for instance, in [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=682412))

```
export http_proxy=http://username%40domain.com:password@host:port
```